# What are the differences in angular controller notation?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I've have seen a couple of notations to initialize a controller in angular, those are:

```
app.controller('nameCtrl', function($scope, ... ){})
```

and

```
app.controller('nameCtrl', ['$scope','...',function($scope,...){}])
```

Both work, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation that spot the differences, does it even matter?

Answer (score 5):

```
app.controller('nameCtrl', function($scope, ... ){})
```

The above won't work with minification, but the below will.

```
app.controller('nameCtrl', ['$scope','...',function($scope,...){}])
```

Comment: is that it?... so it is a big deal, right? Could you please provide a link with information related?

Comment: It's because minifiers/uglifiers change argument names to very short names, like a or b, to reduce code size. AngularJS dependency injection relies on argument names to inject a certain type. See "A note on minification" at http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05.