# AngularJS Controller notation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, templates, controller

I'm working on a Themeforest-Template,where the controllers looks like this:

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular.module("app.tables", []).controller("articlesCtrl", ["$scope", "$http",
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('www/articles.php?method=fetchAll').success(function (data) {
            $scope.articles = data;
            console.log($scope.articles);
        }).
            error(function (data) {
                // log error
            })
    }
])}.call(this))
```

Everywhere in the web I find guides and tutorials where the controllers looks like this:

```
app.factory('articlesFactory', function ($http, $resource) {
$http.get('www/articles.php?method=fetchAll').success(function (data) {
    return $resource(data);
});

app.controller('articlesCtrl', function ($scope, articlesFactory) {
    $scope.articles = articlesFactory.query();
})});
```

why does this not work for me ?

my app.js looks like this:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'easypiechart',
    'textAngular',
    'ui.tree',
    'ngMap',
    'ngTagsInput',
    'app.controllers',
    'app.directives',
    'app.directives',
    'app.localization',
    'app.nav',
    'app.ui.ctrls',
    'app.ui.directives',
    'app.ui.services',
    'app.ui.map',
    'app.form.validation',
    'app.ui.form.ctrls',
    'app.ui.form.directives',
    'app.tables',
    'app.task',
    'app.chart.ctrls',
    'app.chart.directives',
    'app.page.ctrls',
    'app.calls',
    'app.avgLic'
]).config([
    '$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        var routes, setRoutes;
        routes = [
            "calls/calls",
            "calls/archive",
            "calls/statistics",
            "calls/sms",
            "contacts/contacts",
            "configurator/configurator",
            "configurator/offers",
            "configurator/search",
            "configurator/articles",
            "configurator/orders",
            "configurator/distributors",
            "orders/new_orders",
            "orders/archive",
            "avg/active_lic",
            "avg/new_lic"
        ];
        setRoutes = function (route) {
            var config, url;
            url = '/' + route;
            config = {
                templateUrl: 'views/' + route + '.html'
            };
            $routeProvider.when(url, config);
            return $routeProvider;
        };
        routes.forEach(function (route) {
            return setRoutes(route);
        });
        return $routeProvider.when('/', {
            redirectTo: '/calls/calls'
        }).when('/404', {
            templateUrl: 'views/pages/404.html'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/404'
        });
    }
]);}).call(this);
```

Comment: I can explain the difference in declaration however I fail to understand what does not work for you? Can you post error message?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977082/what-are-the-differences-in-angular-controller-notation

Comment: Error-Message: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/ng/areq?p0=articlesCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

Comment: How about an output from your chrome web developer console?

Comment: this message is out of the console...