# What is the difference between these two angularjs controller definition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I don't understand the difference between these two types of angularjs controller definition,
i have tried following codes and found both working

```
myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First one cares about minification.

In this controller:

```
myApp.controller('GreetingController', function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
});
```

arguments will be minimized to some short values and dependency injection will not work.

Please look at:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation
- https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05
- [What are the differences in angular controller notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977082/what-are-the-differences-in-angular-controller-notation)

Comment: So the best practice is to use the first method? Or depends where do you use it?

Comment: @Crysis85 it depends. Second method is safe even when you are doing minification. There are some grunt and gulp tools which are appending this injection points automatically for you. Take a look at https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate

Answer (score 1):

The second one won't work anymore once minified, because the minifier will rename the parameters to spare as much bandwidth as possible:

```
myApp.controller('GreetingController', function(a) {
    a.greeting = 'Hola!';
});
```

Since angular uses the *names* of the arguments to know what to inject to the controller, that will fail.

The first syntax is a way to circumvent this problem.

I use [ngAnnotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) in order to automatically transform the second syntax to the first one, as part of the build process, before minifying